# Is there any way to send notifications via FCM for android without going through expo's server?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, expo

I'm using React Native with Expo. I created the project using `create-react-native-app` command.
I'd like to send remote notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging for android device without going through expo's server.

`eject` is the only way?
It's ok only for android.

reference:
https://docs.expo.io/versions/v27.0.0/guides/push-notifications
https://docs.expo.io/versions/v27.0.0/guides/using-fcm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should eject it and then use some libraries like https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm (this is the one that I use), it is well documented.

If you do not want to use the library directly, you can use OneSignal or something like that.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The Expo guide for using FCM is here:https://docs.expo.io/versions/v29.0.0/guides/using-fcm

It says that FCM "is required for all new standalone Android apps made with Expo".

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I configured Expo Notifications few hours ago, and I noticed that you can send push to Android both ways, using Expo Push tool but using Firebase as well: the only thing you have to do is store your ExpoToken in Firebase.
You are not forced to eject from Expo.

In the flow asking permission to send notifications, you obtain from Expo a token, in a format like **ExponentPushToken[i4uCznGitg$84t****a343]**.

You can save as an external component this code:

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {

let token;
if (Constants.isDevice) {
  const { status: existingStatus } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
  let finalStatus = existingStatus;
 
  if (existingStatus !== 'granted' || Platform.OS === 'android') {
  
    const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();

    finalStatus = status;
  }
  if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
    //alert('Failed to get push token for push notification!');       
    return;
  }
  token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;
         
} else {
  // alert('Must use physical device for Push Notifications');    
}

if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('default', {
    name: 'default',
    importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
    vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
    lightColor: '#FF231F7C',
  });
}

return token;
}
export default registerForPushNotificationsAsync;
```

The obtained token can be stored in your db (if you want to use it further through Expo push), but you could send it to Firebase to store it.
In your Firebase project you can divide Android and iOS, and saving those separately in different topics.

Do a test: obtain a ExpoPushToken, store it in Firebase, then send to it a test push, you will see that it works perfectly.

As explained in Expo docs ([Using FCM for Push Notifications](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/using-fcm/)), if you want to use Expo to send notifications to Android, you must set it sending your Server Token

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.